# Forcing a .Net Windows service to run as 32-bit on a 64-bit machine

Tags: .net, configuration, 64-bit

I've been given a windows service which references a COM component that only runs on 32-bit. 
My machine is x64, so the service tries to start, fails to create the COM component, and dies.

I don't have the source, just the .exe file. Is there any way to force a service to start in 32-bit mode on a win64 machine?

Answer (score 73, accepted):

Maybe the .NET tool [*corflags*](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms164699.aspx) will help:

`corflags /32bit+ myservice.exe`

Comment: +1 for the great answer, but the options come last:
Usage: Corflags.exe Assembly [options]

Comment: I had a problem where I got the message 

`corflags : error CF001 : Could not open file for writing`

the solution was to add /force

Comment: Same problems are for services built as .dll and debugged in VS through WcfSvcHost. In this case, you can switch the flag on the WcfSvcHost itself. [see article](http://coding.abel.nu/2012/04/debugging-a-wcf-service-using-a-32-bit-dll/)

Answer (score 2):

corflags.exe comes with the Windows SDK, not .NET.

corflags.exe needs to run only once against the target service exe.  Then the service will run in 32-bit mode thereafter.

Note the argument needed is /32bitreq+ or /32bitpref+ .

corflags.exe /32bitreq+ myservice.exe