# ODBC C# Issue - The specified DSN contains an architecture mismatch between the Driver and Application

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net-4.0, 4d-database

I am integrating 4D database into C#.Net based application which is developed in Framework 4.0. I have successfully created the DSN using 64 bit version since the drivers are only available for 64 bits. The application pool is also referring to 64 bits application but I am getting the following exception while trying to open the connection -

System.Data.Odbc.OdbcException: 'ERROR [IM014] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] The specified DSN contains an architecture mismatch between the Driver and Application'

Can anyone advise what is wrong in this ? I am unable to fix the issue.

Comment: The following may be helpful: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/34497/32-bit-odbc-driver-on-64-bit-sql-server and [ODBC .NET 32 bit and 64 bit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22774226/odbc-net-32-bit-and-64-bit) which states: _ODBC Data Source Administrator is different for 32bit and 64bit drivers. **ODBC 64bit** driver use `c:\windows\system32\odbcad32.exe`
and for **ODBC 32bit** driver use `c:\windows\sysWOW64\odbcad32.exe`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ODBC .NET 32 bit and 64 bit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22774226/odbc-net-32-bit-and-64-bit)

Comment: I will go through the above articles @user9938